# What if you wish for someone's marriage break?

Tags: allah

I saw a video on Facebook of a marriage ceremony where the wife was being too touchy with husband's friend. After seeing the video I wished the marriage should break. I don't know what came to me. I regret what I said. Will Allah forgive me?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. "Wish" is a very vague expression. AFAIK if you play an active role in a separation of two married people your action is regarded as highly sinful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu,
Surely Allah is often forgiving expect when you associat partner with him.
Ask for Allah true forgive and repent.

And next time when some thing like that happen just pray for those couple because by Allah your pray for them can do the best for them

Wasalamu alaikum

Answer (score 0):

Yes Allah will forgive you because he's often forgiving and Allhadulillahi you have understand that what you do is wrong, so don't try it again